# What if "variable.parameter.function.coffee" in Sublime Text's syntax definition?

Tags: sublimetext

I saw it here: https://github.com/aponxi/sublime-better-coffeescript/blob/master/CoffeeScript.tmLanguage#L32

But as the docs told, `variable.parameter` told there's no children for it,
http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language_grammars

Why this is happening in CoffeeScript's package?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to is just a guide, not a strict set of rules. They were developed for TextMate so that color schemes could have a small number of scopes and still highlight everything appropriately. Sublime is not TextMate, and there are no hard and fast rules for what scopes should apply to what type of syntax element. In general, syntax authors mostly stick with the recommendations in the link, but not always, and there are plenty of gray areas. Any item can be subclassed to make it more specific, as is the case with the CoffeeScript scope you referenced. A color scheme can have a particular color for `variable.parameter`, or it could have different colors for `variable.parameter.function` and `variable.parameter.function-call`, allowing you to differentiate between parameters defined in the function definition, and parameters passed when calling a function.